# MicroSD Card Slot SPI Signals

Tags: spi, debugging, microsd

I am having trouble communicating with an microSD card with an AVR on a board I'm working on. I used an oscilloscope to have a look at the signals coming out of the microSD socket on my board. I saw nice 3.3V MOSI and SCK signals between the AVR and the microSD socket. What I saw on the MISO trace however surprised me. It looked kind of like a superposition of the MOSI and SCK scaled down to under 100mV. My interpretation of this is that the MISO line must be floating and what I'm seeing on the scope is basically cross talk / AC pickup from adjacent signal traces.

The possible causes of this that I've come up with are:

- The Slave Select trace is not making it all the way to the SD card (i.e. either the SD slot is not well connected to the board on that pin or the card is not making good contact within the slot)

  - My reasoning on this is that if the card were powered and the Slave Select pin were low the card would actively drive the MISO line (i.e. it would not float).
- Likewise for the 3.3V power or GND signals to the card

  - My reasoning on this is that if the card were not getting power / GND, it wouldn't matter what was happening on the SPI bus.

My questions are:

1. Are the conclusions I'm drawing sound based on the information I've provided?
2. Are there other possibilities I've overlooked?
3. How can I isolate / diagnose the problem further?

**Edit #1**

The following scope trace illustrates the description I gave above:

[image]

Comment: What's stopping you from checking your connections? Also, adding scope shots might help.

Comment: @Armandas it's difficult to know what is going on inside the microSD slot with the microSD card seated. As far as I can tell the microSD slot mounted to the board properly.

Comment: @Armandas I may be able to get a scope capture to post later tonight.

Comment: @Armandas scope trace added for your viewing pleasure

Comment: Thanks. As far as connections are concerned, I think it should be pretty safe to assume that if the signals are getting to the card holder (you should be able to check that), they are also getting to the card. As for the waveforms, that looks pretty bad. It's hard to believe that this is just a pickup. At this point, I can only suggest to thoroughly check the connections and make sure the I/Os are configured properly.

Comment: To me it seems something more than crosstalk, because not only the edges, but also the "DC" levels are the same...seems like one of the devices is "leaking" the signal from the other lines to the MISO line

Comment: Finally, try a different card. I was in a situation, where the card would stop working after some time, and would only come back to life with a scope probe (or a finger :)) attached to the clock line.

Comment: @clabacchio did you notice that channel one is set to 200mV/division and is not always positive? The MISO line is being fed into a level shifting 74HC4050PW buffer (that's where I probed it) and the only other "active" device on that line is the microSD card...

Comment: Yes, but look when MOSI is low: it also puls MISO lower. But now I see that it's like exponentially going to 0, so I don't know. Maybe it's only coupling, but it's quite clear that nothing is driving it properly.

Comment: Do you have a schematic you could post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just looked at an example circuit from Microchip http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/DS-51583b.pdf

It shows a pull up resistor on the MISO line to the card. It's possible that the card has an open collector output that needs a pull-up resistor on your board to work.

Comment: My circuit is based directly on http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/DevTools/Arduino/microSD_Shield-v13%20Schematic.pdf

Comment: @vicatcu - That's nice, but I'd trust Microchip over Sparkfun every time.  Microchip is a member of the SD Association, Sparkfun is not. It's possible that *some* cards have an open collector output, and that Sparkfun hasn't seen these cards, or that some SD cards have weak internal pullups while others have totem-pole outputs, or...any number of things.  Get your schematics from the most official source possible.

Comment: @KevinVermeer that is good advice, and I'll add pull-ups to the MISO pin in my next revision of the board definitely... I think I will generate a new question about my overall SPI design topology

Comment: The reason I suggested what I did was not so much just that Microchip does it so you should to, but rather based on the weird signal he's seeing on the MISO line. Usually when I see a signal like that it's because I don't have the I/O pin configured correctly or I'm missing a pull-up resistor.