# microSD card voltage level- reverse engineering design

Tags: sd, hardware, reverse-engineering

Goal: Adding (back) a microSD socket to a camera that does not have one.

The microSD pads are laid out and appear to be fully connected. Ground is to the ground plane, the data lines are with resistors. When powered up there is 1.6V on the clock line and 3.3V on the MOSI pin (oddly).

However VDD is not connected to anything.

Searching the board on the opposite side there are pads for a SOT-23 device. I've included a photo and, following number conventions, 1 is the lower left, 2 is the lower right, and 3 is the top.

SOT-23-Pad 3 is connected to the VDD pin on the microSD socket.
SOT-23-Pad 2 goes to 3.30V when the unit is powered on.
I can't find a connection to SOT-23-Pad 1, however.
[image: SOT-23 Pad, color 'enhanced' to bring out traces]

So, am I too far off guessing that this is a PNP transistor pad? Of course that leaves not knowing how the base is pulled as there is a couple of other tiny components missing. You can see in the photo that the two component pads on either side are empty. I haven't had luck ohming things out. I thought there was another trace that went high or low depending on if the card was inserted, but I haven't found it.

Since the camera has 'hot swap' (which you'd never do because you have to literally disassemble the whole thing) what would be an good opinion on just bridging the SOT-Pad-2 to SOT-Pad-3?

The software side of the house I believe I've already modified the necessary file, as the UART log (ugly and limited) appears to show scanning for the card.

If you were me, how would you go from here?

Thank you.

References:
http://elm-chan.org/docs/mmc/mmc_e.html
https://www.vishnumaiea.in/projects/hardware/interfacing-catalex-micro-sd-card-module
http://www.dejazzer.com/ee379/lecture_notes/lec12_sd_card.pdf
https://openlabpro.com/guide/interfacing-microcontrollers-with-sd-card/
[MicroSD Card Slot SPI Signals](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31462/microsd-card-slot-spi-signals)

Measured on microsd socket:
3   3.30v
5   1.65v

Pinout of card

```
1   NC      Not used
2   CS      Chip Select
3   MOSI    Master-out, Slave-in
4   VDD     Positive Supply
5   CLOCK   Serial Clock
6   GND     Ground
7   MISO    Master-in, Slave-out
8   NC      Not used
```

Comment: The clock line is "1.65V" because it's a pulsed signal between 3.3 and 0V (so should average somewhere around 1.65V), you would see 3.3V if measuring with an oscilloscope.

Comment: Thank you. I wondered... and I was being very very lazy (my house is a bit... messed...) and didn't really want to get the the oscilloscope out. That's really good to hear though and logically (see what I did there?) it makes sense too. Thank you.